# How to receive XSRF-TOKEN send from asp.net mvc in vue js?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vuejs2, asp.net-web-api2, vuex

At Backend, I have used asp.net web API and I can validate the token by comparing hidden field token and cookies token as shown below:

```
try
{
  string cookieToken, formToken;
  AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);

  CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers
                                    .GetCookies(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
  if (cookie != null)
  {
    Stream requestBufferedStream = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    requestBufferedStream.Position = 0;
    NameValueCollection myform = Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;
    try
    {
      AntiForgery.Validate(cookie[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName].Value,
       myform[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw new HttpResponseException(
       new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
    }
  }
}
```

**But I am not able to create  XSRF - token at the frontend using Vue**?
How to create this XSRF validation token at the frontend so that I can later send them back to the backend for validation.

Here, My backend and frontend projects are separate projects.

Anyone there...

Answer (score 0):

The XSRF token has to be created in backend and stored in cookie o local storage in the frontend side.

Check the MS documentation to see examples in vainilla javascript and angular (Vue has to be similar) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2#javascript-ajax-and-spas

Comment: Yes @Andres, it is in asp.net core and wants the same in asp.net MVC. Asp.net MVC doesn't have an IAntiforgery interface. Do you have any other suggestion

Comment: Hi @DiwasPoudel, my mistake... I didn't realize that you are using ASP.Net MCV.

Comment: Hi @DiwasPoudel, my mistake... I didn't realize that you are using ASP.Net MCV. To add this behaviour you have to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` helper in the view inside the Form and add the Attribute `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in the action of the controller who receive the form post. The HTML Helper creates a hidden input and the Attribute validates the its value. You can check a complete example in this link http://blog.at-dot.net/archive/2014/05/13/mvc-what-is-html-dot-antiforgerytoken-and-how-does-it-actually-work/

Comment: In Web Api, we cannot use a filter like [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]. Anyways its okay now .@Andres. :)